# POSIX behaviour with VTIME and read()

Tags: c++, macos, unix, serial-port, posix

After hours spent researching this online, I'm still not quite clear as to how `VTIME` and `read(int fildes, void *buf, size_t nbyte);` work together. It seems to me that as soon as `read()` gets a single byte, then it disregards `VTIME`. `VTIME` is only obeyed when no bytes have been read.

If I'm reading this right, the explanation [here](http://www.unixwiz.net/techtips/termios-vmin-vtime.html) seems to confirm this:

> VMIN = 0 and VTIME > 0
>   This is a pure timed read. If data are available in the input queue, it's transferred to the caller's buffer up to a maximum of nbytes, and returned immediately to the caller. Otherwise the driver blocks until data arrives, or when VTIME tenths expire from the start of the call. If the timer expires without data, zero is returned. *A single byte is sufficient to satisfy this read call*, but if more is available in the input queue, it's returned to the caller. Note that this is an overall timer, not an intercharacter one.

Is there any sort of way to make `read()` return only when `nbyte` has been satisfied *or* when `VTIME` has been reached after the last byte?

It seems a bit weird that `VTIME` and `read()` would act this way. Why wouldn't it try to read `nbytes` before timing out?

As an example, in the below code, `read()` does not wait 10 seconds before it's returned. If no write occurs, then it does.

```
int main (void) {

    int usbSerial;
    struct termios options;
    std::string port = "/dev/tty.usb001";


    usbSerial = open(port.c_str(), O_RDWR| O_NOCTTY | O_NONBLOCK);

    // Check if unopen
    if(usbSerial == -1) {
        printf("Error: Unable to open %s\n", port.c_str());
    }
    else { // Set to blocking
        fcntl(usbSerial, F_SETFL, 0);
        printf("Connection to serial device established.\n");
    }

    // Set port settings
    tcgetattr(usbSerial, &options); // read old port settings
    cfsetispeed(&options, B9600);
    cfsetospeed(&options, B9600);

    options.c_cflag &= ~PARENB;    // set no parity, 1 stop bit, data bits
    options.c_cflag &= ~CSTOPB;
    options.c_cflag &= ~CSIZE;
    options.c_cflag |= CS8;

    options.c_cflag     &=  ~CRTSCTS;           // no flow control.
    options.c_cflag     |=  CREAD | CLOCAL;     // turn on READ & ignore ctrl lines

    options.c_cc[VMIN]   =  0;
    options.c_cc[VTIME]  =  100;


    // Flush port and then apply new options
    tcflush(usbSerial, TCIOFLUSH);
    if (tcsetattr(usbSerial, TCSANOW, &options) != 0) {    // TCSANOW == make option change immediately
        printf("Error %i from tcsetattr.\n", errno);
    }

    // write
    unsigned char message[] = {0x03, 0x05, 0x01, 0x01, 0x04};
    ssize_t n = write(usbSerial, &message, sizeof(message)/sizeof(message[0]));


    unsigned char buffer[64] = {};
    tcdrain(usbSerial);


    ssize_t readChars = read(usbSerial, &buffer, 10);

    printf("Done.\n");

}
```

Comment: Unrelated, but be careful when using the address-of operand with arrays. If the array isn't actually an array (and remember that arrays decays to pointers) then things will most likely not work as expected. And since arrays decays to pointers to their first element you don't actually need the address-of operator when passing arrays to functions expecting pointers.

Comment: The program behavior you describe is not consistent with the code you posted.  Setting VMIN and VTIM is only applicable for non-canonical mode, yet your code does not explicitly configure the serial port for non-canonical or raw mode.  It's possible that the port is already in raw mode, but then you're risking unpredictable program behavior due to partial/incomplete initialization.  More likely your **read()** is a nonblocking canonical operation that uses neither VMIN or VTIME.

Comment: I think it defaults to raw mode because VMIN was working fine, and VTIME too when there were no characters written, but I added `options.c_lflag &= ~(ICANON | ECHO | ISIG);` just to be sure.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe that you are correct when you say:

> It seems to me that as soon as read() gets a single byte, then it disregards VTIME.

Return value for `read()`:

> On success, the number of bytes read is returned (zero indicates end        of file), and the file position is advanced by this number.  It is not an error if this number is smaller than the number of bytes requested; this may happen for example because fewer bytes are actually available right now (maybe because we were close to end-of-file, or because we are reading from a pipe, *or from a terminal*), or because read() was interrupted by a signal. [link](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/read.2.html)

You may have to loop, possibly something like (untested):

```
int totalNeeded = 10;
int remaining   = 10;
while (remaining > 0){
    ssize_t readChars = read(usbSerial, &buffer[totalNeeded - remaining], remaining);
    if (readChars > 0){
        remaining -= readChars;
    }
    else{
        // handle error or EOF
    }
}
```

Not sure how you need to handle partial reads, especially because of `O_NONBLOCK`, but I think that the behavioral interaction between VTIME and `read()` is governed by `read()`.

Comment: Thanks. I expected it to behave similarly to other timeout operations like in pyserial or MATLAB.